# Replacing integers at level 1 in a list with sequences of zeros

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, replacement

I have a list like this:

```
l={{2,3},1,{4,7,2,1},3,{2,2,3,3},0,{4,4,2,1},4}
```

and I want to replace the natural numbers outside the sublists (at level 1) with an equal number of `0`s:

```
replace[l]=={{2,3},0,{4,7,2,1},0,0,0,{2,2,3,3},{4,4,2,1},0,0,0,0}
```

Comment: Depend on @rhermans `If[Head[#] === List, #, Splice@ ConstantArray[0, #]] & /@ l`

Answer (score 11):

**Using `Replace`:**

```
l = {{2, 3}, 1, {4, 7, 2, 1}, 3, {2, 2, 3, 3}, 0, {4, 4, 2, 1}, 4}

Replace[l, i_Integer :> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, i], 1]
```

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
SequenceReplace[l, i : {_Integer} :> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, i]]
```

**Using `Sow/Reap`:**

```
First@Last@
  Reap@Scan[
    If[IntegerQ[#]
      , Sow[Splice@ConstantArray[0, #]]
      (*,Sow@Splice[Table[0,#]]*)
      , Sow@#] &, l
    , {1}
    ]
```

**Using `MapAt`:**

```
MapAt[Splice[Table[0, #]] &, l
 , Position[l, i_Integer, 1]
 ]
```

---

Result:

> {{2, 3}, 0, {4, 7, 2, 1}, 0, 0, 0, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 2,    1}, 0,
> 0, 0, 0}

Answer (score 10):

Similar with @rhermans

```
If[ListQ[#], #, Splice@ConstantArray[0, #]] & /@ l
```

> `{{2, 3}, 0, {4, 7, 2, 1}, 0, 0, 0, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 2,  1}, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Answer (score 10):

```
l /. {x : {__Integer} :> x, i_Integer :> Splice[Table[0, i]]}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3}, 0, {4, 7, 2, 1}, 0, 0, 0, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 2, 1}, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

[`ReplaceAll >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

[image: ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts.]

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do this is to use `SplitBy`:

```
Join @@ (If[Length[Level[#, {-1}]] == 1, ConstantArray[0, #], #] & /@ SplitBy[l, Length])

(*{{2, 3}, 0, {4, 7, 2, 1}, 0, 0, 0, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 2, 1}, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)
```

Or using `SplitBy` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
Join @@ (SplitBy[l, Length] /. {{x_Integer} :> ConstantArray[0, x]})

(*{{2, 3}, 0, {4, 7, 2, 1}, 0, 0, 0, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 2, 1}, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)
```